# Why some projected columns in Application Insights queries are not shown at the desired position?

Tags: azure-application-insights

For example, consider this trivial query:

```
datatable(Value:int, ts:datetime) [
    10, datetime(2022-03-30),
    20, datetime(2022-03-30),
    10, datetime(2022-03-31),
    20, datetime(2022-03-31),
]
| project Value, ts
```

The output is:

[image]

Why is `ts` the first column, given that the `project` clause puts it second?

Comment: i believe this is a bug in the logs view's table view?  if you run this same query in workbooks, the columns are in the order they were projected.

Comment: Could you elaborate what do you mean by "workbooks" ?

Comment: The "workbooks" feature of the azure portal:  https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-monitor/visualize/workbooks-overview, which can query AI, LA, ADX, ARM, ARG, etc.  (Also, from inside the logs view, use the "Pin To" toolbar at the top and choose "send to workbook")

Comment: Can you arrange all this information as an answer so I could credit you?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This appears to be a (recent) bug in the Azure Logs view's grid, which they are working on fixing.  (depending on what build you can see, you can possibly already drag to re-arrange them the way you want)

Other views that can query Log Analytics, like the [Azure Workbooks UX](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-monitor/visualize/workbooks-overview) or the [Azure Data Explorer UI](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-explorer/query-monitor-data) won't have the same issue.

(eventually it will also be fixed in Logs view as well)

One way to get to Azure Workbooks from inside Log Analytics view, use the "Pin To" toolbar at the top and choose "send to workbook".